# Basic bash script for terminal prompt

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Currently my terminal prompt includes git information.

Example clean directory: michaelespinosa:~/Sites/example.com [git:master]
Example dirty directory: michaelespinosa:~/Sites/example.com [git:master*]

I want also to color the git information (green if it's clean or red if it's dirty).

I thought I could add a function (parse_git_color) and set it's color accordingly with an if else statement based of whether or not an asterisk is present.

The problem is that it keeps returning green for both clean and dirty directories. I believe the problem has something to do with the if statement parse_git_dirty == "*" that compares the value value of parse_git_dirty to "*".

```
function parse_git_dirty {
  [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" ]] && echo "*"
}
function parse_git_color {
  if [ parse_git_dirty == "*" ]; then
    echo '\033[0;31m\'
  else
    echo '\033[0;32m\'
  fi
}
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/$(parse_git_color)[git:\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note the `\$(...)` in PS1. It is important because only with `\$()` your command is called every time your prompt is printed. `$()` is called only once (when PS1 was initialized).

```
function parse_git_dirty
{
  [[ "$(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1)" != "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" ]] && echo "*"
}

function parse_git_color
{
  if [ "$(parse_git_dirty)" == "*" ] ; then
    echo "0;31m"
  else
    echo "0;32m"
  fi
}

function parse_git_branch
{
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/[git:\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}

export PS1="\[\033[\$(parse_git_color)\]\$(parse_git_branch) \[\033[0m\]"
```

Comment: I updated to your suggestion, but it didn't work. I ended up with michaelespinosa:~/Sites/example.com 033[0;32m[git:master]. I think the problem has something to do with the if statement, because it keeps returning the else no matter what.

Comment: @michaelespinosa Sry, I didn't test my suggestion. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks @sgibb the key was changing parse_git_dirty to "$(parse_git_dirty)"

Comment: With changes in the git status message, this would break. Be sure to match the comparison after the `!=` in `parse_git_dirty` with the default message for a clean repository. For instance, 1.8.2 has a different message for clean repositories and `parse_git_dirty` would always return `"*"`